# How to check when a bookmark placed inside a cell?

Tags: java, openoffice-writer, uno

Is there any way to check if a bookmark placed inside a table cell? If so, how could I also get the cell's indices (row and column)?

Thought about using something like `XTextViewCursor`, but I don't know how to get a cell cursor in order to compare cursors positions.

(Non-java solutions also acceptable, I just want to get the idea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently bookmark anchors work like the [TextRange](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/TextRange.html) interface.  See `7.1.2 Can I check the current selection for a TextTable or Cell` in Andrew Pitonyak's macro document.

The following python example checks if the anchor is located in a table cell.  If it is, it gets the cell name, from which we can determine the row and column.

```py
def is_bookmark_in_cell():
    doc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
    marks = doc.getBookmarks()
    anchor = marks.getByName("MyMarkInCell").getAnchor()
    cell = anchor.Cell
    if cell:
        cellName = cell.CellName
    else:
        # Bookmark is not in a cell.
```

In my test, the cell name was `B2`.  For simple tables, `B2` simply means the second row and the second column.  It may be more complex with tables that have rows spanning multiple columns, or columns spanning multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

There is a java solution, based on the @JimK's answer:

```
XTextRange bookmark = getBookmarkByName(bookmarkName);
XPropertySet props = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XPropertySet.class, bookmark);
Object maybeCell = props.getValue("Cell");
XCell cell = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XCell.class, maybeCell);
```

You could also extract `"TextTable"` from the `props` and then retrieve `"CellName"` from the `cell`'s properties.